# How can I calculate normals using a vertex and index buffer?

Tags: mathematics

Is it possible to calculate normals using the positions in a vertex buffer and index buffer? Would someone show pseudocode for the algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried to look it up? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350792/calculate-normal-of-a-single-triangle-in-3d-space) by quick googling.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is, here is how you can do:

Every vertex in the vertex buffer is represented by one index which may occur several times in the index buffer.
What you first need to do is to make a function that for a index returns the corresponding vertex.
Should be fairly trivial.

I am going to assume that the mesh is rendered as GL_TRIANGLES

```
for every 3 indexeses in index buffer
  edge1 = index1 - index2
  edge2 = index1 - index3

  var normal = edge1 cross edge2
```

Simple as that! This normal can either be sent once for every 3 vertices making up a face, or one time for every 3 vertices

This normal though, will be a face normal, meaning that you will get a flat looking shading, so what you might want to do is calculate the interpolated per vertex normals.
What you do then is that you for every vertex keep a map that tells which face this vertex belongs to.
Then for all vertexes you take all faces that this vertex belongs to, take their normals, add them together and then normalize the resulting vector.
Maybe you should even weight the face normals according to size of the face

Answer (score 3):

Another user was struggling to implement this with the existing answer, so I thought I'd show a slightly deeper code example for folks in a similar situation.

I'll use Unity C# syntax since it's what I use most often, but the same steps can be applied to any language/framework.

```
CalculateVertexNormals(Vector3[] vertexPositions, int[] triangleIndices, Vector3[] vertexNormals)
{

    // Zero-out our normal buffer to start from a clean slate.
    for(int vertex = 0; vertex < vertexPositions.Length; vertex++)
        vertexNormals[vertex] = Vector3.zero;

    // For each face, compute the face normal, and accumulate it into each vertex.
    for(int index = 0; index < triangleIndices.Length; index += 3) {
        int vertexA = triangleIndices[index];
        int vertexB = triangleIndices[index + 1];
        int vertexC = triangleIndices[index + 2];    

        var edgeAB = vertexPositions[vertexB] - vertexPositions[vertexA];
        var edgeAC = vertexPositions[vertexC] - vertexPositions[vertexA];

        // The cross product is perpendicular to both input vectors (normal to the plane).
        // Flip the argument order if you need the opposite winding.    
        var areaWeightedNormal = Vector3.Cross(edgeAB, edgeAC);

        // Don't normalize this vector just yet. Its magnitude is proportional to the
        // area of the triangle (times 2), so this helps ensure tiny/skinny triangles
        // don't have an outsized impact on the final normal per vertex.

        // Accumulate this cross product into each vertex normal slot.
        vertexNormals[vertexA] += areaWeightedNormal;
        vertexNormals[vertexB] += areaWeightedNormal;
        vertexNormals[vertexC] += areaWeightedNormal;
    }       

    // Finally, normalize all the sums to get a unit-length, area-weighted average.
    for(int vertex = 0; vertex < vertexPositions.Length; vertex++)    
        vertexNormals[vertex] = Vector3.Normalize(normal);
}
```

Comment: What about vertices that x,y,z are negative? This makes normal point inward and a part of mesh get black.

Comment: https://imgur.com/FYTpnn1

Comment: @JanisTaranda: Inward/outward is not determined by the sign of the xyz components of the vertex coordinates. It's determined by the winding order of the triangle indices. If you find this applies to some of your triangles but not others, then you probably have inconsistent winding order. Exchange two of the indices in a triangle to flip it back out the other way.

Comment: From your image it looks like you're visualizing your normals as colour. For those cases, it's absolutely normal that a vector pointing in the -x,-y,-z octant comes out black. For this reason when we're visualizing normals, we often set `(r,g,b) = ((x,y,z) + 1f)/2f` to map the range of valid normals into the range of displayable colours.

Comment: That solved the normal visualization part. Thank you. However when calculating diffuse lights (`float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);`) the normal is used, and again that area is super dark and seems to be cut off.

Comment: @JanisTaranda We do not need to handle negative vectors differently in lighting. What you describe sounds like the expected and desired result if the light is shining from the other side of your object. A surface whose normal faces away from the light should be in shadow. If your light is coming from (-1,-1,-1), then its dot product with a normal in the (-x,-y,-z) octant will be positive, even though all the components are negative — the signs cancel and the math "just works". You might just be missing a fill/bounce/ambient light in your scene, making the shadowed sides look too flat and dark.