# handling obj file without normal

Tags: opengl, shaders, opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to build an obj file loader and I have written code to read an obj file with face *f* with *v/vt/vn* - vertex, texture coordinate, and normal.

While going through the obj file, there are so many files without normal coordinates.

My shader code in Fragment shader is:

```
float lambertianFactor = clamp(dot(normal, lightDirectionNormalized), 0.0, 1.0);
vec3 diffuseTextureData = texture(diffuseSampler, v_texCord).rgb;
vec3 effectiveDiffuse = diffuseTextureData*diffuse*lambertianFactor*directionalLight;    
effectiveDiffuse = diffuseTextureData*diffuse*lambertianFactor;
```

for obj file without normal coordinate but with diffuse texture, how am I supposed to handle diffuse lighting?

Comment: Have you considered [computing normal vectors on import, based on your vertex positions and triangle indices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/152991/39518)?

Comment: thank you @DMGregory, I was clueless because no article and post is suggesting anything. Does this mean I need to learn from different sources? I am self-learning WebGL and computer graphics. Is there any source you suggest that will help me in times like this ? and thank you for saving me

Comment: This is my rendering with obj file with Normal !!! 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWCrGjsQq4c

Comment: If that solved your problem, then I'll mark this question as a duplicate of the one I linked. If you still need help, you can edit the question and we can re-open it, or you can post a new question.

Comment: i think it will be a good lead to your answer through the post for another person who has no idea whether they need to generate a normal or create a workaround without normal data. Like me who had no idea whether to generate a normal or do another thing !!!